# How to convert an array like string to array in node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Actually I'm getting the `arraylist` from android device in `node.js` . But as it's in string form so I wanna convert it into an `array` . For that I've referred a lot of similar questions in `SO` but none of them were helpful . I also tried to use `JSON.parse()` but it was not helpful.

I'm getting societyList in form **'[Art, Photography, Writing]'**.Thus how to convert this format to an array?

Code:

```
var soc_arr=JSON.parse(data.societyList)
            console.log(soc_arr.length)
```

Comment: Define `societyList` like `'["Art", "Photography", "Writing"]'` then `JSON.parse()` should work fine

Comment: @Satpal sir that's the problem how to do that dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use something like this

```
var array = arrayList.replace(/^\[|\]$/g, "").split(", ");
```

#### UPDATE:

After @drinchev suggestion regex used.

regex matches char starts with '[' and ends with ']'

Comment: Even better `list.replace(/^\[|\]$/, "").split( ", " );` :)

Comment: @drinchev oups thats not correct can you verify your regex ? im getting a bracket at the last string like ["Art", "Photography", "Writing]"]

Comment: Oops sorry `list.replace(/^\[|\]$/g, "").split( ", " )`

Comment: This will break for `["Hello, World", "Hi"]`

Comment: ```var array = arrayList.replace(/^\["|"\]$/g, "").split('", "');``` should fix it (for valid JSON), but as someone pointed out the example string is not valid json

Answer (score 3):

This string is not valid JSON since it does not use the `""` to indicate a string.

The best way would be to parse it yourself using a method like below:

```js
let data = '[test1, test2, test3]';
let parts = data
  .trim() // trim the initial data!
  .substr(1,data.length-2) // remove the brackets from string
  .split(',') // plit the string using the seperator ','
  .map(e=>e.trim()) // trim the results to remove spaces at start and end
  
console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 2):

[RegExp.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) maybe

```js
 console.log('[Art, Photography, Writing]'.match(/\w+/g))
```

So `match()` applies on any string and will split it into array elements.

Comment: except in this case you assume each array element is a single word made entirely of ASCII letters. That may be a stretch.

Comment: @Touffy not really much to go in in the question

Comment: I agree. Which is why you shouldn't make assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace` and `split`. In addition, use `trim()` to remove the trailing and leading whitespaces from the array element.

```js
var str = '[Art, Photography, Writing]';
var JSONData = str.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',').map(x => x.trim());
console.log(JSONData);
```