# How to convert a string containing an array into an Array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the following string: '[a, b]'
I want to get an array which looks like this: ["a", "b"]

This is the code I have written:

```js
const string = '[a, b]'
const array = string.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replaceAll('\'', '').split(',')
console.log(array)
```

My code solves the issue I have but I want to know if there is a better way to do this compared to what I have done.

Comment: maybe you could change the source of the string to get a [json](https://json.org/) compliant string instead.

Comment: A better way would be to fix whatever your data source is to provide you properly encoded data like JSON. Not to have to jump through hoops and still get potentially wrong result out of it.

Comment: '[a, b]' is not a valid string representation of an array of strings.

Comment: Maybe this is the thing you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056956/how-to-convert-an-array-like-string-to-array-in-node-js

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just strip off the first and last characters and then split on `', '`?  Basically the same thing you did but less code

```js
const str = '[a, b]';

console.log(str.slice(1, -1).split(', '))
```

Comment: That's exactly what the OP already does in the working code in the question. The OP is asking for a better solution. Why do you think your solution is better than theirs?

Comment: I wouldn't say exactly.  I mentioned it's "basically the same thing", but their code is about ~68% slower https://jsperf.app/kucufi

Comment: But their code is working and produces a different result for other cases. I would consider your answer wrong, because it doesn't handle brackets and single quotes.

Comment: It gives a different result even in the case they provided - my code gives the desired array from their question `["a", "b"]`, their code gives a slightly different array from what they said they wanted, `[ "a"," b"]`

Answer (score -3):

Your question is not entirely clear

### If your string is always `'[a, b]'`:

You can just do:

```
const result = ['a', 'b']
```

because it doesn't make sense to parse anything

### If your string is like `'[a, b]'` or `'[x, d]'`

1. Use `str.replace(/[a-z]/g, '"$&"'` to change `a` into `"a"`
2. Use `JSON.parse` to parse the string

```js
const str = '[a, b]'
const result = JSON.parse(str.replace(/[a-z]/g, '"$&"'))
console.log(result)
```

`/[a-z]/g` can be replaced with any other regex depending of how complicated your substrings are e.g. `/[a-zA-Z\d]+/g` will accept longer substrings with varying case and numbers

It's a better solution because converting just the invalid parts and then using `JSON.parse` makes it harder to make a mistake.

---

But the most reliable solution would be to change your initial string to be a valid json

Comment: fails for `str = '[A, B]'` and `str = '[a1, b1]'` Among others inputs.

Comment: @VLAZ op said that they have the following string `'[a, b]'` and not `'[A, B]'` or `'[a1, b1]'`

Comment: In that case the answer should be `result = ["a", "b"]` no  reason to do replacing and parsing if it's literally just that one string and no other, no?

Comment: Why is your solution better than the working solution in the question? It seems like the code in the question is more stable than yours. What are the advantages of your solution?

Comment: Solutions may differ depending on what 'a' and 'b' can be. Can they contain spaces? Is there some defined pattern to their content (e.g. always single letters?). as written, the problem space is incompletely defined.

Comment: Your code produce a different output than the code in the question.